# Is there a template for creating Xamarin projects using the dotnet CLI?

Tags: xamarin, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to get in the spirit of using the dotnet CLI command line to create my projects and solutions. Is there a template that will create the stock Xamarin solution that I currently create using Visual Studio? When I type:

```
dotnet new --list
```

I don't see anything related to Xamarin.

Comment: No, I haven't. What part of that article do you think is related to my question?

Comment: This link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/233356/is-it-possible-to-use-xmarin-app-using-net-cli-or.html) has you same problem.